# A searchbox using select and input for older browsers(no flexbox)

Tags: css

I want to create a search box, by using a select and an input.
I have 2 issues:

- I want the search input to fill all the remaining space(see the grey background);
- Select and input to be connected, no space between them(because of DOM space)

Because I need to work older IE, I can't use flexbox or grid; I tried also float.

Looking for a solution where select and input width is flexible, not fixed;

I tried a trick, (in comments, `width: 1%`) that sometimes works, but not with select;

```css
.searchbox { 
display: table;
width: 500px;
background-color: grey;
}

select, .form-group{ 
  display:table-cell;
  margin:0;
}

/*select {
width:1%;
space:nowrap;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="searchbox">
 <select>
  <option>Abras</option>
  <option>Brat</option>
  </select>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input placeholder="Search" name="q""/>
    <span>icon_placeholder</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I posted an answer but I guess halfway through working it out I forgot about the older browser support part. How old are you trying to go back?

Comment: ie9 maybe, IE10 yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**this**](https://caniuse.com/#search=float) `float:` will not work in IE9, but if you use `-ms-` it should work in IE10 +. I was reading around and although the website I listed said it's not supported in IE9 im finding articles of people being able to use it. Let me know if you have any issues with the following code.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  -ms-float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.options {
  width: 75px;
}

.search {
  width: calc(100% - 110px);
}

.image {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.style {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0;
}

.full {
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left options">
    <select class="left style">
      <option>Abras</option>
      <option>Brat</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="left search">
    <input class="style full" placeholder="Search" name="q" />
  </div>
  <div class="left image">
    <img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/C/company-leaf-and-flames-logo-2ECEE07FDD-seeklogo.com.png" alt="img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the display for the select to `display: inline-block;` aligns everything to the left.

This won't center align the fields vertically if you choose to change the height later, but I think it solves your problem.

```
select, .form-group { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't extend the input search to the remaining space;if I'm wrong please write in editor

Answer (score 0):

You can float the select and then turn the **.form-group** div into a block formatting context, doing this will make it respect the floats position and fill the remaining space making it dynamic. See the demo below and [click here to read more about block formatting contexts](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/understanding-css-layout-block-formatting-context/)

```css
.searchbox { 
display: table;
width: 500px;
background-color: grey;
}

/* select, .form-group{ 
  display:table-cell;
  margin:0;
} */

select {
  float: left;
}

.form-group {
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* keep box model properties subtracted from width not added */
}
```

```html
<div class="searchbox">
 <select>
  <option>Abras</option>
  <option>Brat</option>
  </select>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input placeholder="Search" name="q"/>
    <span>icon_placeholder</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

There are many ways to turn an element into a block formatting context, I have opted to set the overflow property to hidden.

If you want an element to sit on the right of **.form-group** make sure to add it before the **.form-group** element in your mark up and float it right. The **form-group** will then fill the remaining space in the middle of the 2 floated elements.

*Lastly when using floats don't forget to clearfix your container*